# Tensorflow on mac

Tags: python, macos, numpy, tensorflow

I tried to import tensorflow on my mac 10.11.6. There is the error message.
The version of numpy is 1.8.0rc1, version of Python is 2.7.10.

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I tried to upgrade my numpy by pip install numpy --upgrade
Then I got...

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.12.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hm/xzmwbxxj01q0n5dm61hwv6ww0000gn/T/pip-vc6iST-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

What should I do now? 
Thanks !!!

Comment: You might consider just installing anaconda, probably won't have any troubles under that environment, and let's face it, you're going to need all those packages that it comes with eventually.